# Is it possible to improve sort perfomance of ID-based list of rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance, sql-optimization

Consider following example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    CREATE TABLE #Users
    (
        ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Name    VARCHAR(50)
    );
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Users_UserID ON #Users(ID);

  --  CREATE INDEX IDX_Users_Name ON #Users(Name); -- It doesn't work.

    CREATE TABLE #Towns
    (
        ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Name    VARCHAR(50)
    );
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Towns_UserID ON #Towns(ID)

    CREATE TABLE #BeenHere
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), -- for some business reason we can't use clustered index on them
        UserID INT,
        TownID INT
    );

    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_BEEN_THERE ON #BeenHere(TownID, UserID);


    INSERT INTO #Towns
    SELECT Prefix+Suffix FROM (
        SELECT Prefix, Suffix FROM
        (SELECT 'China' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Ham' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Chicken' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Great' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Loud'
        ) as A(Prefix)
        CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT 'town' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'water' UNION ALL
         SELECT ' City' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'burg' UNION ALL 
         SELECT 'berg') AS B(Suffix)
    ) Q
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    ;


    INSERT INTO #Users(Name)
    SELECT Name + ' ' + Surname FROM (
        SELECT Name, Surname FROM
        (SELECT 'John' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Mary' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Ann' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Salomon' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Lisa' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Patricia' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'David' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Patrick' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'John' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Harry' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Richard' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'George'
         ) as A(Name)
         CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT 'Smith' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Kowalski' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Bush' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Truman' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Clinton' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Reagan' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Lincoln' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Goldberg' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Adams' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Wilson' UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Carter') as B(Surname)

    ) P
    ORDER BY NEWID();


    INSERT INTO #BeenHere(UserID, TownID)
    SELECT 
        TOP 10 PERCENT
        #Users.ID,
        #Towns.ID
        FROM
        #Users
        CROSS JOIN
        #Towns
        ORDER BY NEWID();

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

SELECT 
    Towns.Name,
    (SELECT Users.ID, Users.Name FROM #Users Users INNER JOIN #BeenHere BH ON Users.ID = BH.UserID WHERE BH.TownID = Towns.ID ORDER BY Users.Name FOR XML PATH('User'), ROOT('Users'), TYPE) as BeenThere
    FROM #Towns Towns
    ORDER BY Towns.Name;

DROP TABLE #BeenHere;
DROP TABLE #Users;
DROP TABLE #Towns;
```

As we can see in execution plan, sorting users cost 78% of resources consumed by last query.

Is it possible to place some index on these tables to improve sorting perfomance? I can't introduce backward incompatible changes to database, like providing clustered index on `#BeenHere(UserID, TownID)`.

Comment: No, we can't see anything in execution plan because you haven't included it.

Comment: Just a reminder, the percentages in the plan are only estimates

Comment: Well on the first create index you have closed it out with a ;    Why even have ID INT IDENTITY at all in #BeenHere.   Why are fragmenting the heck out of the indexes with the newID sort on the inserts?

Comment: " Why even have ID INT IDENTITY at all in #BeenHere" -> because legacy database I'm dealing with uses this pointless convention. "Why are fragmenting the heck out of the indexes with the newID sort on the inserts" -> because it's better simulation of real-world data that I have to deal with.

Comment: Anything you can do with a CI you can do with an NCI. Just include all required columns. Then you get almost identical physical data structure.s

Comment: OK but you missed to most important thing.  You are closing out the first statement with a ;    Did you dry taking it out?

Answer (score 1):

I simply replaced your clustered index into this one:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Users_Name_UserID ON #Users(Name, ID);
```

So now your table is sorted by `Name`, not by `ID`.

`SORT` operator is gone from execution plan.
[image]

**UPDATE**
As you said, you cannot change clustered index. There's one way to do that if you want. Your `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on Name only column is fine, but SQL Server decides not to use it. What you can do is to add a HINT to your table to use this index:

```
SELECT Towns.Name
    , (
        SELECT Users.ID, Users.Name
        FROM #Users Users WITH (INDEX (IDX_Users_Name))
        INNER JOIN #BeenHere BH
            ON Users.ID = BH.UserID
        WHERE BH.TownID = Towns.ID
        ORDER BY Users.Name
        FOR XML PATH('User'), ROOT('Users'), TYPE
        ) AS BeenThere
FROM #Towns Towns
ORDER BY Towns.Name;
```

Then your query will use this index and sort operator will no longer be there. However, I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way. SQL Server has to Scan index then, instead of seeking it.
[image]

Comment: I hadn't use foreign keys to simplify test case. Anyway - I can't made such change, because it will require to modify hundreds of tables and hundreds of SPs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the use of a correlated subquery. Stop using those and use joins (including derived tables if you must) instead. Correlated subqueries run row-by-row and not against the whole set and thus are preformance hogs. one.

Comment: It will cripple client that expects XML fields (legacy codebase).